# Updating Connection String in DLL from Winforms - Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I developed a class library that uses Linq To Sql to communicate with a database.

When I added this I used Server Explorer to add a database and all the tables I want to talk to.

It then built a .dbml file for me.

In the "Designer" file I can see:

```
public TPDataContext() : 
            base(global::TPAPI.Properties.Settings.Default.TruePotentialConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

If I update the "Linq to SQL" it regenerates a new designer.cs file

It stored the connection string in Settings.settings with the scope of "Application".

All functions just fine.

But, I have then added a winfoms project that needs to change this setting. So I added the following code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["TPAPI.Properties.Settings.TruePotentialConnectionString"].ConnectionString = txtConnectionString.Text;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

This updates the connection string in the dll but it only takes effect when the application is shutdown and restarted.

When I am upgrading clients it overwrites what the user had already entered when using it previously.

I cannot seem to work out the best way to:

1. Not overwrite previous user defined connection string when the app is upgraded.
2. Be able to save the new connection string and use it without having to stop/start the app.

Having had a read of other threads it appears that the dll shouldn't really have any "local" settings in it (?) and they should all be sent by the winforms app. But, I am unclear on how use Linq to Sql in the dll without it automatically looking/adding it's own connection string.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to rewrite all my DataContext calls to accept the connection string parameter.

I had to amend and test about 40 functions but now the connection string is stored in the winforms application as a user setting and overrides the default connection string generated by Linq to SQL.

So, now in my dll it now looks like

```
TPDataContext db = new TPDataContext(connStr);
```

HTH